# Create a 70%-30% relation between my classes

Tags: r, class

I have unbalanced data, let's say: 2% bad and 98% good.

What I want to do now is to repeate the bad classes until I have reached (for example) a 70% bad and 30% good relation.

I know this is a rather unusual method ( I already tried SMOTE) but I am just curious for the results.

I will use this data to apply decision tree on it.

Example data:

```
> df

class   percentage     color  

bad        0.45        green
bad        0.67        red
bad        0.34        blue
good       0.22        black
good       0.25        pink
good       0.89        green
good       0.76        yellow
good       0.35        grey
good       0.44        red
good       0.99        red
good       0.12        blue
good       0.56        black
good       0.70        pink
good       0.49        yellow
```

Output would be:

```
> df

class   percentage     color  

bad        0.45        green
bad        0.67        red
bad        0.34        blue
bad        0.45        green
bad        0.67        red
bad        0.34        blue    
bad        0.67        red
bad        0.34        blue
bad        0.45        green
bad        0.45        green
bad        0.67        red
bad        0.34        blue
bad        0.45        green
bad        0.67        red
bad        0.34        blue
bad        0.45        green
bad        0.67        red
bad        0.34        blue
bad        0.45        green
bad        0.67        red
bad        0.34        blue
bad        0.45        green
bad        0.67        red
bad        0.34        blue
good       0.22        black
good       0.25        pink
good       0.89        green
good       0.76        yellow
good       0.35        grey
good       0.44        red
good       0.99        red
good       0.12        blue
good       0.56        black
good       0.70        pink
good       0.49        yellow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd say that you should avoid this, because you may end up with a non rapresentative sample of the truth.

In fact you just replicate those 3 cases. `SMOTE` should be a better approach to rebalance things.

Anyway, here's a way of doing this:

```
do.call("rbind", replicate(n_bad, d_bad, simplify = FALSE))
```

The main thing is this line that replicates bad cases.

```
library(dplyr)
# we set some parameters that you can play with
n_rows_final <- 100
perc_bad <- 0.7
bad_cases <- nrow(d %>% filter(class=="bad"))

n_bad <- (n_rows_final*perc_bad)/bad_cases # nrows final * desired perc bad
n_good <- (n_rows_final*(1-perc_bad)) # nrows final * desired perc good

# filter the original data
d_bad <- d %>% filter(class=="bad")
d_good <- d %>% filter(class=="good")

set.seed(123)
d_good <- d_good[sample(n_good), ] # sample n_good cases

d_bad <- do.call("rbind", replicate(n_bad, d_bad, simplify = FALSE)) # replicates bad cases n_bad times

d_final <- rbind(d_bad, d_good) # binds
table(d_final$class)
# bad good 
#  69   11
```

Data:

```
tt <- "class   percentage     color  
bad        0.45        green
bad        0.67        red
bad        0.34        blue
good       0.22        black
good       0.25        pink
good       0.89        green
good       0.76        yellow
good       0.35        grey
good       0.44        red
good       0.99        red
good       0.12        blue
good       0.56        black
good       0.70        pink
good       0.49        yellow"

d <- read.table(text=tt, header=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but it should work:

```
class <- c("bad","bad","bad","good","good","good","good","good","good","good","good")
val <- rnorm(length(class))
df <- data.frame(class, val)

# calculate number of bad rows required
n <- round(sum(df$class == "good") * (7/3)) - sum(df$class == "bad")

# create df of bad rows to sample from
bad.df <- df %>% filter(class == "bad")

# sample rows n times and create df of required size
s <- sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE)
bad.df <- bad.df[s, ]

# bind to original df
df2 <- bind_rows(df, bad.df)
prop.table(table(df2$class))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(134)
d %>%
  group_by(class) %>% 
  sample_n(size = 100, replace = T) %>% 
  split(.$class) %>% 
  map2(.,c(0.3, 0.7), ~mutate(.x, gr=sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), size = n(), replace = T, prob = c(1-.y, .y)))) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(gr) %>% 
  select(-gr)
# A tibble: 101 x 3
   class percentage color
   <fct>      <dbl> <fct>
 1 bad         0.45 green
 2 bad         0.34 blue 
 3 bad         0.34 blue 
 4 bad         0.67 red  
 5 bad         0.67 red  
 6 bad         0.34 blue 
 7 bad         0.45 green
 8 bad         0.34 blue 
 9 bad         0.67 red  
10 bad         0.34 blue 
# ... with 91 more rows

.Last.value %>% 
  count(class)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  class     n
  <fct> <int>
1 bad      71
2 good     28
```

The idea is to sample both groups to same size (here to 100, but you can increase to 100ths.). Then add a filter variable `gr` with corresponding probabilities 70:30.